# Quip Live Apps API in windows

Tags: quip, liveapps

https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/issues/39

> I got it working in MAC, it wasn't working in Windows. Strange!! thank you

I have the same problem, I want it work in windonws, is there any way. Or it is not possible in Windows. Please tell me thanks